# идентификатор "Node" не определен

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
class List {
public:

    List();
    ~List();
    void append(Node object); //Тут ошибка

private:

    class Node {
    public:

        Node* pNext;
        class Date {
        public:
            int day;
            int month;
            int year;
        };

        Date object;

        Node(Date object, int day, int month, int year, Node* pNext = nullptr) {
            this->object.day = day;
            this->object.month = month;
            this->object.year = year;
        }
    };

    int Size;
    Node* head; //Указатель на первый элемент списка
};
```

Не могу понять, почему не могу обратиться ни к классу Ноуд ни к структуре Дєйта

Comment: Потому что он должен быть объявлен перед использованием, а не после.

Comment: Не могу понять причём тут это, это же класс

Comment: Потому что в момент обращения они не определены.Откуда в классе `List` компилятору знать, что такое `Node`? Он не нерадивый ученик, в конец учебника не лезет, читает все подряд... Перенесите функцию в конец, после `Node`. И, кстати, сделайте ее `private` - все равно ею кроме как из класса List пользоваться будет нельзя. И я бы не полагался на конструктор копирования `Node` по умолчанию (который будет вызываться при передаче `Node` по значению).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)